# Twig loop index into array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, indexing, twig

I want to show my string value into my array 'nameComments' with key `{{loop.index}}` of my comments array, but `{{ nameComments[{{ loop.index }}] }}` show an error

```
{% for com in comments %}
    <p>Comment {{ nameComments[{{ loop.index }}] }} : "{{ com['comment'] }}"</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If I try:

```
{% for com in comments %}
    <p>Comment {{ nameComments[1] }} : "{{ com['comment'] }}"</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And the `{{ loop.index }}` show me value : `1`

So how can I implement my loop index into my array?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
{% for com in comments %}
    <p>Comment {{ nameComments[ loop.index ] }} : "{{ com['comment'] }}"</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Just leave out the curly brackets. This should work fine.
By the way `loop.index` is 1 indexed. If you loop through an array which normally starts with index 0 you should consider using `loop.index0`

See the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

Comment: Excellent to take note of `loop.index0`. This can get you crazy when you forget about that !! ;-)

Answer (score 9):

It is safer to iterate over the real value of the array index and not using loop.index and loop.index0 in case where array indexes do not start in 1 or 0 or do not follow a sequence, or they are not integers.

To do so, just try this:

```
{% for key,com in comments %}
    <p>Comment {{ nameComments[key] }} : "{{ com['comment'] }}"</p>
{% endfor %}
```

See the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values)